# Saving Core Data related data and retrieving with NSPredicate and NSFetchedResultsController with multiple entities

Tags: core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I'm fairly new to Core Data and am still trying to understand accessing and filtering related data. My problem is either I'm not getting the data correctly into the managedObjectContext or I'm not pulling it out correctly. (I think the first, but I'm not sure.)

Here's my data model with two entities related one to many: (I plan to refactor once I get one level of relationship working.)

[image]

I have a SeasonsVC in which you click on a season name and the list of games for that season is supposed to appear in the GamesVC and you have the option to add or edit an existing game. This works fine at a first pass. I can add and edit games via this code in the GameDetailsVC:

```
 -(IBAction)done:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender {

    Game *game = nil;

    if (self.gameToEdit != nil) {
        game = self.gameToEdit;
        NSLog(@"Hitting gametoedit");
    } else {
        game = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Game" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
        NSLog(@"Hitting new game");
    }

    game.opponent = self.opponentTextField.text;
    //season.seasonDescription = self.seasonDescriptionTextView.text;

    NSLog(@"Game to edit: %@", game.opponent);
    //NSLog(@"Season: %@", season);

    //NSLog(@"MOC in done: %@", self.managedObjectContext);
    //NSLog(@"Season name: %@", season.seasonName);

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

I can then see the games in the GamesVC via the fetchedResultsController and delegate methods, but each game is associated with every season. Once I try to filter the data with a predicate so that I only see the games that were added for that season all the games disappear.  Here's the code for that from the GamesVC:

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {

    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription
                                   entityForName:@"Game" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    NSLog(@"Season name for predicate %@", self.season.seasonName);//shows correct season name

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"season.seasonName like '%@'", self.season.seasonName]];

    [fetchRequest setPredicate: predicate];


    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"dateOfGame" ascending:NO] ;

    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:@[sortDescriptor]];

    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

    NSFetchedResultsController *theFetchedResultsController =
    [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                        managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                                   cacheName:@"Root2"];
    self.fetchedResultsController = theFetchedResultsController;
    self.fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

    return _fetchedResultsController;

}
```

Since I can log the correct season name right before the predicate statement, I think that the added games are not getting "associated" with the correct season when I put them in the MOC in the done: method shown above; otherwise, I'd expect the predicate to find them.

Can you help this rookie?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A day later I have this sorted. I needed to make three changes to what I was doing.

First, in my prepareForSegue in my GameListVC I needed to pass the season along to the GameDetailsVC by changing the code to this. (Just added the one line: controller.season = self.season)

```
    //pass the Season object to be edited
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:sender];
    Game *gameToEdit = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    controller.gameToEdit = gameToEdit;
    controller.season = self.season;
```

Second, I had to put the new/edited game object into the MOC by adding these two lines to my done: method in the GameDetailsVC.

```
NSMutableSet *games = [self.season mutableSetValueForKey:@"games"];
[games addObject:game];
```

Third, I needed to simplify my predicate statement in my fetchedResultsController method in the GameListVC.

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"season.seasonName like %@", self.season.seasonName];
```

So, to answer my own question, I was both not saving the game linked to the season and my predicate was wrong.

I hope some of this helps another rookie.